# How to group by batch of rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

A process records a batch of data (e.g. `batch_size = 27`) from multiple iterations (e.g. `n_iterations = 10`) and flattens them into a CSV file. In this case, the file would have `270` rows. I need to group/aggregate the data by batch to be able to calculate metrics like average, median and standard deviation on the `Duration` field. The entries in the `Name` field repeat and have the same order within each batch, so `df[0]["Name"] == df[batch_size]["Name"]`, but might not be unique within each batch.

```
    Name    Duration
0   A       9.664
1   B       25.184
2   A       10.656
3   C       9.408
4   D       8.608
... ... ...
265 A       9.920
266 D       4.064
267 A       11.616
268 B       13.664
269 A       9.440
```

The final result should be a dataframe with `batch_size` rows that contains all Durations as columns `Duration_{i}`, or as a list `[Duration_0, Duration_1, ...]`, or directly the statistical metrics `Duration_mean`, `Duration_median`, ... as columns. Any format is acceptable.

```
    Name    Duration_0  Duration_1  ...
0   A       9.664       7.221       ...
1   B       25.184      24.110      ...
... ...     ...         ...         ...
25  B       13.664      12.853      ...
26  A       9.440       8.502       ...
```

or

```
    Name    Duration
0   A       [9.664, 7.221, ...]
1   B       [25.184,  24.110, ...
... ...     ...
25  B       [13.664, 12.853, ...]
26  A       [9.440, 8.502, ...]
```

or

```
    Name    Duration_mean   Duration_median ...
0   A       9.552           8.997           ...
1   B       24.444          24.321          ...
...
25  B       13.521          13.415          ...
26  A       9.440           9.502           ...
```

How can this be done with Pandas?

EDIT: Simpler data for verification with `batch_size=3` and `n_iterations=2`:

Input:

```
    Name    Duration
0   A       1           -+
1   B       2            | batch_0
2   A       2           -+
3   A       5           -+
4   B       2            | batch_1
5   A       4           -+
```

Output:

```
    Name    mean
0   A       3   // from (1+5)/2
1   B       2   // from (2+2)/2
2   A       5   // from (0+10)/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need aggregate per `n_batch` rows with first value of `Name` per groups and Duration aggregate by `mean` and `median` use:

```
n_batch = 3
g = df.index % n_batch
df = df.groupby(g).agg(Neme=('Name','first'),
                        Duration_mean=('Duration','mean'),
                        Duration_median=('Duration','median') )

print (df)
  Neme  Duration_mean  Duration_median
0    A              3                3
1    B              2                2
2    A              3                3
```

Comment: I think this works, but the variable `n_batch` in your example actually corresponds to `n_iterations` in mine. I've updated my code above to use `batch_size` (number of entries per batch) and `n_iterations` (number of repetitions of equally-sized batches) to avoid confusion.

Comment: @leosh - Hard understand for me without full data output for verify my solution. So I suggest use `np.random.seed(10)`
`df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFG'), size=20),
                   'Duration':np.random.random(size=20)})` and then how looks expected ouput?

Comment: @leosh - e.g. if `n_iterations=5`, `n_batch=4` ? Because still not understand how is necessary grouping. Thanks.